# Image in React Native

Tags: react-native

- [Image when works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOpGh.png)
- [Image when doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivWrc.png)
- [doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wfcxZ.png)
- [works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Juanz.png)

variable image and property of the item are the same.
Why it doesn't work?
Thank you for any help

```
const avatars = [
  {
    _id: "01",
    image: "../assets/images/avatar01.png",
  },
  {
    _id: "02",
    image: "../assets/images/avatar01.png",
  },
];
```

`const image = "../assets/images/avatar01.png";`

While source is {require("../assets/images/avatar01.png")} or {require(image)} it works, and
when I try set to {require(item.image)} it doesn't

```
      <View
        className="absolute inset-0 z-10"
        style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight }}
      >
        <ScrollView>
          <BlurView
            className="px-4 py-16 flex-row flex-wrap items-center justify-evenly"
            tint="light"
            intensity={40}
            style={{ width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight }}
          >
            {avatars?.map(
              (item) => (
                console.log(item.image === image),
                (
                  <TouchableOpacity
                    className="w-20 h-20 m-3 p-1 border-2 rounded-full "
                    key={item._id}
                  >
                    <Image
                      source={require("../assets/images/avatar01.png")}
                      className="w-full h-full"
                    />
                  </TouchableOpacity>
                )
              )
            )}
          </BlurView>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add local image array like following ,

```
    const avatars = [
    {
      _id: '01',
      image: require('./assets/1.png'),
    },
    {
      _id: '02',
      image: require('./assets/2.png'),
    },
  ];
```

and use them like this ,

```
{avatars?.map(item => (
    <TouchableOpacity key={item._id}>
      <Image source={item.image} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  ))}
```